# auctex preview-latex does not take into account newcommands

Tags: macros, auctex, preview

I have slightly complex symbols that I do not want to re-type in latex so I define `\newcommand`s that abbreviate them. For example

```
\begin{document}
blah blah

\newcommand{\ds}[1]{\Delta\{#1\}}

\[
  \{x\} := \ds{a} + \ds{b_1} + \ds{c}
\]

blah blah
\end{document}
```

But when using `preview-latex` the `\ds` command is not recognized. Is there a way around this?

I am using auctex 12.3, emacs 26.3 and `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)`.

EDIT: It was pointed out that `\newcommand{ds}{...}` should be `\newcommand{\ds}{...}`. I edited the post to add the `\` because that was a valid correction but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of `\newcommand` requires a backslash for the command to be defined: so not `\newcommand{ds}{...}`, but `\newcommand{\ds}{...}`

```
\begin{document}
  blah blah
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\Delta\{#1\}}
  %%         ^^^
 \[
 \{x\} := \ds{a} + \ds{b_1} + \ds{c}
 \]

 blah blah
 \end{document}
```

Comment: While the answer is essentially correct, some more words would be better, also avoiding to litter the code with something that inexperienced users might want to imitate.

Comment: @egreg sorry, i just wanted to highlight the faulty command. Fortunately there are good reviewers on tex.se. Thank you.

Comment: You are right but that didn't actually solve the problem. Preview-latex still ignores the `newcommand`s.